# unable to connect to network on ubuntu in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

When I do `ping google.com` on the host (Win7) I get 74.125.227.164 and am able to ping without issue.

When I do `ping 74.125.227.164` on Ubuntu (my VirtualBox guest OS) I get a `connect: Network is unreachable` message.

Here's the output of ifconfig:

[image]

I've tried doing `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and then `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` and they appear to run without issue. What's interesting is that `ping 74.125.227.164` actually worked *before* I did the ifconfig stuff. Doing it in fact seems to have in fact made things worse - not better.

Doing `cat /etc/resolv.conf` gives me the following:

```
nameserver 10.128.128.128
```

Here's a copy of my virtualbox settings:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try *sudo dhclient eth0*, and see whether you can connect.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing the VirtualBox additions inside the VM.  This will provide drivers to the guest OS to use the adapters provided by VirtualBox.

Another option I'd recommend is using the "bridged adapter" instead of NAT.

It could also be that the ARP table got corrupted while you were changing settings.  You can try clearing the ARP cache using [THIS](http://www.linuxhelp.in/2011/09/clearing-arp-cache-in-linux.html) as a guide.

Since you're using a live CD, you can restart and the settings all revert back to normal.

Comment: I'm running an Ubuntu LiveCD. I'd have to eject the CD (which would probably kill the OS) to insert another one containing the VirtualBox additions..

Comment: Then try the bridged adapter setting and see if that works.

Comment: I did - didn't help :(